# replace values in a data set based on user input

Tags: r, shiny

I want to update a dataframe (A) using another dataframe (B). B is in `ui` and the user has option to update data in table B. Based on updated values in B, I want to update A. See the code below, the code allows user to update B but A is not getting updated after clicking action button:

```
df2 <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 4L, 0L, 1L), 
                      B = c("3", "*", "*", "2"), 
                      C = c("4", "5", "2", "*"), 
                      D = c("*", "9", "*", "4")), 
                 .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
                 class = "data.frame", 
                 row.names = c(NA, -4L))
df1 <- structure(list(variable = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
                      Value = c(2L,1L, 9L, 0L)), 
                 .Names = c("variable", "Value"), 
                 class = "data.frame",
                 row.names = c(NA, -4L))
shinyApp(
  ui <-
    fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Sample"),

      # Create a new row for the table.
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput("select", label = h3("Select Variable"), 
                      choices = unique(df1$variable), 
                      selected = unique(df1$variable)[1]),
          numericInput("num", label = h3("Replace * with"), 
                          value = unique(df1$variable)[1]),
          actionButton("applyChanges", "Apply Changes")),
        mainPanel(
          dataTableOutput(outputId="table")
        ))),
  Server <- function(input, output) {

    # Filter data based on selections
    output$table <- renderDataTable({
      df1$Value[df1$variable==input$select] <<- input$num
      df1
    })
    df2_new <- eventReactive(input$applyChanges,{
      df1[as.character(df1$variable)] <- Map(function(x, y)
        replace(x, x=="*", y), df2[as.character(df1$variable)], df1$Value)
      df2_new <- df2
      return(df2_new)
    })
  })
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: You might want to use `reactiveValues`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you intend I think:

```
library(shiny)
# old df2
dfaa <- data.frame(A = c( 1L, 4L, 0L, 1L), 
                   B = c("3","*","*","2"), 
                   C = c("4","5","2","*"), 
                   D = c("*","9","*","4"),stringsAsFactors = F) 
# old df1
dfbb <- data.frame(variable = c("A","B","C","D"), 
                  Value    = c( 2L, 1L, 9L, 0L),stringsAsFactors = F)

ui <-  fluidPage(titlePanel("Sample"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("select", label = h3("Select Variable"), 
                  choices = unique(dfbb$variable), 
                  selected = unique(dfbb$variable)[1]),
      numericInput("num", label = h3("Replace * in A with"), 
                   value = unique(dfbb$Value)[1]),
      actionButton("applyChanges", "Apply Changes specified in B to A")),
    mainPanel(
      h3("Table A"),  dataTableOutput(outputId="tableA"),
      h3("Table B"),  dataTableOutput(outputId="tableB")
)))

server <- function(input, output) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(dfA=dfaa,dfB=dfbb)
  observe({
    # update dfB immediately when the variable or value in the ui changes
    rv$dfB$Value[rv$dfB$variable==input$select] <- input$num
  })

  observeEvent(input$applyChanges,{
    # Here we apply the changes that were specified
    dfAcol <-as.character(rv$dfB$variable)
    rv$dfA[dfAcol] <- 
          Map(function(x, y) replace(x, x=="*", y), rv$dfA[dfAcol], rv$dfB$Value)
  })
  output$tableB <- renderDataTable({ rv$dfB })
  output$tableA <- renderDataTable({ rv$dfA })
}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Notes:

- It is actually pretty close to the original code you posted.
- To implement the data updating I used `reactiveValues` and `observe` instead of `eventReactive`, you could do it with `eventReactive` as I mentioned before and you tried, I tried it too, but this way was
  cleaner and clearer and avoided the dreaded `<<-`.
- Added Table B to the main panel so as to see what is going on.
- I re-named `df2` to `dfaa` and `df1` to `dfbb`. I just could not keep `df1` as  Table B and `df2` as Table A in my head, it was too confusing.
- I also made the initializer more human friendly - `dput` output is hard to read.
- The `map` and the `input$num` assignment would be more clearly done with `dplyr`. I recommend using `dplyr` as it really does make for cleaner and less error-prone code.
- I pulled out the `ui` and `server` functions from the `shinyApp` call, this gives you more indentation room and the more common pattern.

Mandatory screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @ Mike Wise A big thank you. I am new to R and still struggling to write codes. Thanks for the help again!

Comment: A small question. Is there an option to commit the changes made in ui permanent in data sets? The changes should be seen even after closing the ui in global environment? Thanks in advance

Comment: Not in ui. You can only write code that executes in the server part. However nothing to prevent you from putting together an action button that is wired to an observeEvent, that then does a write.csv to a file that you want.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again!

Comment: @ Mike Wise: I am stuck with a new problem in the same above code. Can you help in that? Would highly appreciate it. The link of new question is below   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43182663/dependencies-in-functions-two-functions-working-individually-but-when-combined