# Dependencies in functions. Two functions working individually but when combined in code are showing error in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, reactive

I have 2 separate codes which work individually (Code A and Code B). When I club these codes to create single app, it shows error when both inputs are updated. Not sure where the error is?

Code A

```
library(shiny)
dfaa <- data.frame(A = c( 1L, 4L, 0L, 1L), 
                   B = c("3","*","*","2"), 
                   C = c("4","5","2","*"), 
                   D = c("*","9","*","4"),stringsAsFactors = F) 
dfbb <- data.frame(variable = c("A","B","C","D"), 
                   Value    = c( 2L, 1L, 9L, 0L),stringsAsFactors = F)

dfbb["Drop_Variable"] <- "No"                 

ui <-  fluidPage(titlePanel("Sample"),
                 sidebarLayout(
                   sidebarPanel(
                     selectInput("select2", label = h3("Select any other Variable to drop"), 
                                 choices = unique(dfbb$variable), 
                                 selected = unique(dfbb$variable)[1]),
                     selectInput("select3", label = h3("Yes/No"), 
                                 choices = list("Yes", "No"),
                                 selected = "No"),         
                     actionButton("applyChanges", "Apply Changes specified in B to A")),
                   mainPanel(
                     h3("Table A"),  dataTableOutput(outputId="tableA"),
                     h3("Table B"),  dataTableOutput(outputId="tableB")
                   )))

server <- function(input, output) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(dfA=dfaa,dfB=dfbb)
  observe({
    # update dfB immediately when the variable or value in the ui changes

    rv$dfB$Drop_Variable[rv$dfB$variable==input$select2] <- input$select3
  })

  observeEvent(input$applyChanges,{
    drop <- as.character(rv$dfB$variable[rv$dfB$Drop_Variable == "Yes"])
    rv$dfA <- rv$dfA[,!(names(rv$dfA) %in% drop)]     
  })
  output$tableB <- renderDataTable({ rv$dfB })
  output$tableA <- renderDataTable({ rv$dfA })
}
       shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Code B

```
library(shiny)
dfaa <- data.frame(A = c( 1L, 4L, 0L, 1L), 
                   B = c("3","*","*","2"), 
                   C = c("4","5","2","*"), 
                   D = c("*","9","*","4"),stringsAsFactors = F) 
dfbb <- data.frame(variable = c("A","B","C","D"), 
                   Value    = c( 2L, 1L, 9L, 0L),stringsAsFactors = F)

dfbb["Drop_Variable"] <- "No"                 

ui <-  fluidPage(titlePanel("Sample"),
                 sidebarLayout(
                   sidebarPanel(
                     selectInput("select", label = h3("Select Variable"), 
                                 choices = unique(dfbb$variable), 
                                 selected = unique(dfbb$variable)[1]),
                     numericInput("num", label = h3("Replace * in A with"), 
                                  value = unique(dfbb$Value)[1]),
                     actionButton("applyChanges", "Apply Changes specified in B to A")),
                   mainPanel(
                     h3("Table A"),  dataTableOutput(outputId="tableA"),
                     h3("Table B"),  dataTableOutput(outputId="tableB")
                   )))

server <- function(input, output) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(dfA=dfaa,dfB=dfbb)
  observe({
    # update dfB immediately when the variable or value in the ui changes
    rv$dfB$Value[rv$dfB$variable==input$select] <- input$num

  })

  observeEvent(input$applyChanges,{
    # Here we apply the changes that were specified
    dfAcol <-as.character(rv$dfB$variable)
    rv$dfA[dfAcol] <- 
      Map(function(x, y) replace(x, x=="*", y), rv$dfA[dfAcol], rv$dfB$Value)

  })
  output$tableB <- renderDataTable({ rv$dfB })
  output$tableA <- renderDataTable({ rv$dfA })
}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Combined Code A and B

```
library(shiny)

dfaa <- data.frame(A = c( 1L, 4L, 0L, 1L), 
                   B = c("3","*","*","2"), 
                   C = c("4","5","2","*"), 
                   D = c("*","9","*","4"),stringsAsFactors = F) 

dfbb <- data.frame(variable = c("A","B","C","D"), 
                   Value    = c( 2L, 1L, 9L, 0L),stringsAsFactors = F)

dfbb["Drop_Variable"] <- "No"                 

ui <-  fluidPage(titlePanel("Sample"),
                 sidebarLayout(
                   sidebarPanel(
                     selectInput("select", label = h3("Select Variable"), 
                                 choices = unique(dfbb$variable), 
                                 selected = unique(dfbb$variable)[1]),
                     numericInput("num", label = h3("Replace * in A with"), 
                                  value = unique(dfbb$Value)[1]),
                     selectInput("select2", label = h3("Select any other Variable to drop"), 
                                 choices = unique(dfbb$variable), 
                                 selected = unique(dfbb$variable)[1]),
                     selectInput("select3", label = h3("Yes/No"), 
                                 choices = list("Yes", "No"),
                                 selected = "No"),         
                     actionButton("applyChanges", "Apply Changes specified in B to A")),
                   mainPanel(
                     h3("Table A"),  dataTableOutput(outputId="tableA"),
                     h3("Table B"),  dataTableOutput(outputId="tableB")
                   )))

server <- function(input, output) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(dfA=dfaa,dfB=dfbb)
  observe({
    # update dfB immediately when the variable or value in the ui changes
    rv$dfB$Value[rv$dfB$variable==input$select] <- input$num
    rv$dfB$Drop_Variable[rv$dfB$variable==input$select2] <- input$select3
  })

  observeEvent(input$applyChanges,{
    # Here we apply the changes that were specified
    dfAcol <-as.character(rv$dfB$variable)
    rv$dfA[dfAcol] <- 
      Map(function(x, y) replace(x, x=="*", y), rv$dfA[dfAcol], rv$dfB$Value)
    drop <- as.character(rv$dfB$variable[rv$dfB$Drop_Variable == "Yes"])
    rv$dfA <- rv$dfA[,!(names(rv$dfA) %in% drop)]     
  })
  output$tableB <- renderDataTable({ rv$dfB })
  output$tableA <- renderDataTable({ rv$dfA })
}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: Yeah, that is not going to work - except maybe once. You probably need to work with three tables, one root table that does not ever change, and always apply the changes specified in table B to that root table to get table A.

Comment: Also base R does not work well with empty conditions. Which is why people tend to move to using libraries like `dplyr` and `data.table` that are more programmer friendly.

Comment: Can you tell me what you mean by empty conditions? Trying to learn R and Shiny still :D

Comment: Deals with results like no data.frame columns being left, or just one column left.

Comment: Note this post. You program fails if you only leave one column no being dropped. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737452/prevent-automatic-conversion-of-single-column-to-vector. You need to add a `,drop=TRUE` to the final calculation of `rv$dfA` like I just did.

Comment: `dplyr` doesn't have these problems, but it isn't so good at this kind of meta-programming either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a couple of small changes, that however imply a big architectural change. I added a "root Table-A", and reinitialize table-A with that before anytime you apply changes. Otherwise the operations simply often do not make any sense and are operating on empty data.

The only changes I made (I think) were:

- added a definition of an additional data frame (`rootdfaa`) that we will never change.
- added `rootdfaa` to the ui output panel because I find it helps to see it (since it never changes it isn't really necessary). I have a very big screen too so it is no issue for me :)
- added a line to `observeEvent` to reinitialized `rv$dfA` every time we "apply changes"
- added a `dror=FALSE` statement to the final calculation of df$A to keep R from turning a single column result into a vector instead of a dataframe.

I **do** think this is the only way to approach this - trying to guard all those expressions so that they will work iteratively on potentially missing data will be a nightmare.

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)

rootdfaa <- data.frame(A = c( 1L, 4L, 0L, 1L), 
                       B = c("3","*","*","2"), 
                       C = c("4","5","2","*"), 
                       D = c("*","9","*","4"),stringsAsFactors = F) 

dfaa <- rootdfaa

dfbb <- data.frame(variable = c("A","B","C","D"), 
                   Value    = c( 2L, 1L, 9L, 0L),stringsAsFactors = F)

dfbb["Drop_Variable"] <- "No"                 

ui <-  fluidPage(titlePanel("Sample"),
                 sidebarLayout(
                   sidebarPanel(
                     selectInput("select", label = h3("Select Variable"), 
                                 choices = unique(dfbb$variable), 
                                 selected = unique(dfbb$variable)[1]),
                     numericInput("num", label = h3("Replace * in Tab-A with"), 
                                  value = unique(dfbb$Value)[1]),
                     selectInput("select2", label = h3("Select any other Variable to drop"), 
                                 choices = unique(dfbb$variable), 
                                 selected = unique(dfbb$variable)[1]),
                     selectInput("select3", label = h3("Yes/No"), 
                                 choices = list("Yes", "No"),
                                 selected = "No"),         
                     actionButton("applyChanges", "Apply changes in Tab-B to Tab-A")),
                   mainPanel(
                     h3("Root Tab-A"),  dataTableOutput(outputId="roottableA"),
                     h3("Tab-A"),  dataTableOutput(outputId="tableA"),
                     h3("Tab-B"),  dataTableOutput(outputId="tableB")
                   )))

server <- function(input, output) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(dfA=dfaa,dfB=dfbb)
  observe({
    # update dfB immediately when the variable or value in the ui changes
    rv$dfB$Value[rv$dfB$variable==input$select ] <- input$num
    rowstochange <- rv$dfB$variable==input$select2
    rv$dfB$Drop_Variable[rv$dfB$variable==input$select2] <- input$select3
  })

  observeEvent(input$applyChanges,{
    rv$dfA <- rootdfaa # reinitialze dfA
    # Here we apply the changes that were specified
    dfAcol <-as.character(rv$dfB$variable)
    rv$dfA[dfAcol] <- 
      Map(function(x, y) replace(x, x=="*", y), rv$dfA[dfAcol], rv$dfB$Value)
    drop <- as.character(rv$dfB$variable[rv$dfB$Drop_Variable == "Yes"])
    rv$dfA <- rv$dfA[,!(names(rv$dfA) %in% drop),drop=FALSE]     
  })
  output$roottableA <- renderDataTable({ rootdfaa })
  output$tableB <- renderDataTable({ rv$dfB })
  output$tableA <- renderDataTable({ rv$dfA })
}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

And this is what that looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mike. You always provide the right solution!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be sub-setting the data-table with variable that dont exist when you update it the first time, try subsetting with `%in%`. Also there is small error with `mappy` after but you can sort that out...

Try this:

```
 observeEvent(input$applyChanges,{
    print("two")
    # Here we apply the changes that were specified
    dfAcol <-as.character(rv$dfB$variable)

    rv$dfA[dfAcol] <- 
      Map(function(x, y) replace(x, x=="*", y), rv$dfA[rv$dfA %in% dfAcol,], rv$dfB$Value)
    drop <- as.character(rv$dfB$variable[rv$dfB$Drop_Variable == "Yes"])
    rv$dfA <- rv$dfA[,!(names(rv$dfA) %in% drop)]     
  })
```

Comment: There are more problems there than that though. See my comment.

Comment: Yeah I see that, its easier to re-write the code as its too messy

Comment: Thanks @Pork Chop. But this doesn't eliminate the error. I am new to R and shiny and this is my first code. Will try to read more on it to write better codes!